# EWS - Calendar auto archive

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using Pull Notification and EWS to have synchronization of appointments with Exchange 2010 server and my application.  It works find, I am able to pull notification whenever user create, modify or delete an appointment.

Users have auto archive in their Microsoft Outlook, the auto archive can delete or move appointments in their calendar in Outlook, and notification fired and Pull Notification gets the message and process accordingly, this is correct.

What I want to ask is, is there a way EWS can check whether the notification (delete or modify or move) is fired because of auto archive?

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried using OutlookSpy to look at the archived appointment in the archived folder trying to find is there any property that is related to archive, but no luck :(

Comment: From technet forum, i see someone recommending on PR_ARCHIVE_DATE.  I've tried it but it always return Nothing.